# How can I compute a shifted expanding mean per group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want expanding mean of col2 based on groupby('col1'), but I want the mean to not include the row itself (just the rows above it)

```
dummy = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["a",'a','a','b','b','b','c','c'],"col2":['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'] }, index=list(range(8)))
print(dummy)
dummy['one_liner'] = dummy.groupby('col1').col2.shift().expanding().mean().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
dummy['two_liner'] = dummy.groupby('col1').col2.shift()
dummy['two_liner'] = dummy.groupby('col1').two_liner.expanding().mean().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print(dummy)
---------------------------
here is result of first print statement:
col1 col2
0    a    1
1    a    2
2    a    3
3    b    4
4    b    5
5    b    6
6    c    7
7    c    8
here is result of the second print:
 col1 col2  one_liner  two_liner
0    a    1        NaN        NaN
1    a    2   1.000000        1.0
2    a    3   1.500000        1.5
3    b    4   1.500000        NaN
4    b    5   2.333333        4.0
5    b    6   3.000000        4.5
6    c    7   3.000000        NaN
7    c    8   3.800000        7.0
```

I would have thought their results would be identical.
*two_liner* is the expected result. *one_liner* mixes numbers in between groups.

It took a long time to figure out this solution, can anyone explain the logic? Why does one_liner not give expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `expanding().mean()` and `shift()` within the `groupby()`:

```
groups = df.groupby('col1')
df['one_liner'] = groups.col2.apply(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift())

df['two_liner'] = groups.one_liner.apply(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift())
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2  one_liner  two_liner
0    a     1        NaN        NaN
1    a     2        1.0        NaN
2    a     3        1.5        1.0
3    b     4        NaN        NaN
4    b     5        4.0        NaN
5    b     6        4.5        4.0
6    c     7        NaN        NaN
7    c     8        7.0        NaN
```

Explanation:

```
(dummy.groupby('col1').col2.shift()   # this shifts col2 within the groups 
     .expanding().mean()              # this ignores the grouping and expanding on the whole series
     .reset_index(level=0, drop=True) # this is not really important
)
```

So that the above chained command is equivalent to

```
s1 = dummy.groupby('col1').col2.shift()
s2 = s1.expanding.mean()
s3 = s2.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

As you can see, only `s1` considers the grouping by `col1`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to avoid using `apply` and its consequences on execution time for large datasets:

```py
temp = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        df.rename(columns={"col2": "one_liner"})
        .set_index("col1", append=True)
        .groupby("col1")["one_liner"].shift()
        .groupby("col1").expanding().mean()
        .droplevel(-1)
        .droplevel(0),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

pd.concat(
    [
        temp,
        temp.rename(columns={"one_liner": "two_liner"})
        .set_index("col1", append=True)
        .groupby("col1")["two_liner"].shift()
        .groupby("col1").expanding().mean()
        .droplevel(-1)
        .droplevel(0),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2  one_liner  two_liner
0    a    1        NaN        NaN
1    a    2        1.0        NaN
2    a    3        1.5        1.0
3    b    4        NaN        NaN
4    b    5        4.0        NaN
5    b    6        4.5        4.0
6    c    7        NaN        NaN
7    c    8        7.0        NaN
```

While this is not very sexy, it gets the job done.